Could not load type 'System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext' from assembly 'mscorlib' when calling Flush() on ExtentReports in .NET
I'm working on a .NET project that uses AventStack.ExtentReports to generate test reports. I encounter the following error whenever I call Flush() on the report in my FlushReport method:
Could not load type 'System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

This error occurs specifically at the line where I call extentReport?.Flush(); in the FlushReport method. Here’s the relevant part of my Reporter class:
public static class Reporter
{
    private static ExtentReports extentReport;

    public static void SetUpReport(string path, string documentTitle, string reportName)
    {
        var htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(path);
        htmlReporter.Configuration().Theme = Theme.Dark;
        htmlReporter.Configuration().DocumentTitle = documentTitle;
        htmlReporter.Configuration().ReportName = reportName;

        extentReport = new ExtentReports();
        extentReport.AttachReporter(htmlReporter);
    }

    public static void FlushReport()
    {
        // Finalize the report
        extentReport?.Flush(); // Error occurs here
    }
}

I'm unsure why I'm receiving this error. I looked up some resources online, which suggested that the issue could be due to a conflict between .NET Framework and .NET Core. However, I didn't fully understand the explanation or what specific steps I need to take to resolve this error.

which .net version you are using ? what is the version of your package?
